# Attempting to create a complicated grid layout with batch

Tags: loop, batch

I'm trying to create the following layout using batch, but I can't quite get it right...

### [image]

This is how far I've gotten:

```
{% for entry in items|batch(3) %}
   <div class="row rowDivider">
     {% if loop.index is divisible by(5) or loop.index == 1 %}

        {% for batch in entry[0:3]   %}
          {% if loop.index == 1 %}
              <div class="big">{{batch}}</div>
          {% elseif loop.index == 2 %}
              <div class="big-top">{{batch}}</div>
          {% else %}
              <div class="big-bottom">{{batch}}</div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

      {% elseif loop.index is divisible by(2) %}

        {% for batch in entry[0:2] %}
          {% if loop.index == 1 %}
             <div class="big-left">{{batch}}</div>
          {% else %}
             <div class="small-right">{{batch}}</div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

      {% elseif loop.index is divisible by(3) %}

        {% for batch in entry[0:3] %}
          {% if loop.index == 1 %}
             <div class="small-left">{{batch}}</div>
          {% elseif loop.index == 2 %}
             <div class="small-middle">{{batch}}</div>
          {% else %}
             <div class="small-right">{{batch}}</div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Json used:

```
{ "items": ["1" , "2", "3", "4", "5" , "6", "7", "8","9" , "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22" ] }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it. Here's what I did:

```
{% for entry in items|batch(10) %}
<div class="set">

    {% for batch in entry[0:3] %}
        {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        <div class="rowOne">
          <div class="big">{{batch}}</div>
        {% elseif loop.index == 2 %}
          <div class="big-top">{{batch}}</div>
        {% elseif loop.index == 3 %}
          <div class="big-bottom">{{batch}}</div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for batch in entry[3:2] %}
      {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        <div class="rowTwo">
          <div class="big-left">{{batch}}</div>
      {% elseif loop.index == 2 %}
          <div class="small-right">{{batch}}</div>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for batch in entry[5:3] %}
      {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        <div class="rowThree">
          <div class="small-left">{{batch}}</div>
      {% elseif loop.index == 2 %}
          <div class="small-middle">{{batch}}</div>
      {% elseif loop.index == 3 %}
          <div class="small-right">{{batch}}</div>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for batch in entry[8:2] %}
      {% if loop.index == 1 %}
      <div class="rowFour">
        <div class="small-left">{{batch}}</div>
      {% elseif loop.index == 2 %}
        <div class="big-right">{{batch}}</div>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Had the same problem but yes the solutions is just making the batch bigger. 
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/making-an-entry-grid-with-batch-2-3-2-in-row-then-3-in-row